# How to quit finding of element given under locator strategies of @findbyall when first match gets found?

Tags: selenium

On a page I'm my element has any one of three different identifiers. Having given all three under findByAll, I wish to quit the search for find element as soon as any one of it gets found. Looking for short circuit search for the element, no more search should happen once the element is found.

```
@
iOSXCUITFindByAllSet(value = { @iOSXCUITFindAll(value = {
            @iOSXCUITBy(iOSNsPredicate = "type == 'XCUIElementTypeStaticText' && name == 'Acc_label_Header' && visible ==1"),
            @iOSXCUITBy(iOSNsPredicate = "type == 'XCUIElementTypeStaticText' && name == 'ET NOW - Live Radio' && visible ==1"),
            @iOSXCUITBy(iOSNsPredicate = "type == 'XCUIElementTypeStaticText' && name == 'ET NOW - Live Tv' && visible ==1") }) })
```

Don't want the request for find element to be going as soon as one of the element gets found, as this step of finding element by all locator is taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what language you are using to control selenium. I wrote a bit of code in Javascript which waits for either one of several elements to be visible on the page:

```
// define what we are looking for
let xpathParts = [];
xpathParts.push("//h4[contains(@class,'search-title') and text()='Title 1']");
xpathParts.push("//h3[text()='Title 2']");
xpathParts.push("//h3[text()='Title 3']");
// try to get one of it
let elements = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 50 && elements.length == 0; i++) {
    elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathParts.join("|")));
    await new Promise(s => setTimeout(s, 100));
}
// throw an error if we did not find it within the time
if (elements.lenght == 0) {
    throw "Could not find one of the elements";
}
```